# How to fix USA1013 Fxcop issue

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "SomeFileName",
        Arguments = "args",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

I get the following errors when I use Fxcop on this code:

> USA1013   The namespace 'System.Diagnostics.Process' from the assembly 'System.dll' is not allowed for the local variable 'process' of the method 'Method()' in the class 'ClassName'.

> USA1013   The namespace 'System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StartInfo' from the assembly 'System.dll' is not allowed for the calling 'get_StartInfo' in the method 'Method()' in the class 'ClassName'.

What causes these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: Is that a custom rule? ~ random guess perhaps it wants `using System.Diagnostics;` & `Process process = new Process ...`

Comment: "USA" are not normal warnings.  Crystal ball says that whomever created this rule does not want you to use the Process class.

Comment: @Alex : yes its a custom rule. I tried the same but no luck!

Comment: Ask whomever instituted the rule?

Comment: It is a custom rule specifically defined in your project :)